# Json Schema if/then not working as expected

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to validate a simple json schema and I simply can't seem to get this right. I'm trying to implement this piece of code into JsonSchema, but it doesn't validate correctly.

Code:

```
if (field1 is "REAL") {
    then both attributes.A and attributes.B are present
    if (attributes.field2 is "true") {
        then attributes.C is also present
    }
}
```

I've converted this to a JsonSchema as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "field1": {},
    "attributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field2": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": [
              "REAL"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "$id": "#/properties/realAttributes",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The Attributes Schema",
            "required": [
              "A",
              "B"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "A": {},
              "B": {},
              "C": {},
              "D": {},
              "field2": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": ["REAL"]
          },
          "attributes": {
            "properties": {
              "field2": {
                "enum": ["true"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "required": [
              "C"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The second `if` validation in `allOf` is not working correctly and I can't figure out why. It's failing when I pass `field1`, but not `field2`. [Play with the failing implementation here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/IL9prCf5).

I would expect this to pass, but it reports an error saying that `C` is missing. The failing case:

```
{
  "field1": "REAL",
    "attributes": {
      "A": 4,
        "B": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I can answer your question, but I'm not sure how you arrived at the title of your question. Could you change the title of your question to be a question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema works by applying the schema (and subschemas) to instance locations.

The conditional keywords `if/then/else` work by applying the schema value of `if` to the instance location, and depending on the result, applying `then` or `else` if provided.

The key here is JSON Schema is a constraints based language, and anything you don't specify / constrain is allowable.

Let's take your `if` subschema which isn't working as you expect...

```
{
  "properties": {
    "field1": {
      "enum": ["REAL"]
    },
    "attributes": {
      "properties": {
        "field2": {
          "enum": ["true"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's take a look at what you've specified here.
But first, let's check what `properties` does...

> Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the
> instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child
> instance for that name successfully validates against the
> corresponding schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.2.1

In your `if` subschema, you've said, "*if `field1` exists, it should be "REAL"* " AND "*if the object has a property `attributes`, and if that object value has a property `field2`, then it should be `"true"`* ".

The problem is, if `field1` doesn't exist, and if `attributes` doesn't exist, then the subschema will still pass validation.

If you require the property to be present, you must `require` it.

Let's take a look at your schema having added the `required` keyword...

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "field1": {},
    "attributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field2": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "field1"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": [
              "REAL"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "$id": "#/properties/realAttributes",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The Attributes Schema",
            "required": [
              "A",
              "B"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "A": {},
              "B": {},
              "C": {},
              "D": {},
              "field2": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "field1"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": [
              "REAL"
            ]
          },
          "attributes": {
            "required": [
              "field2"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "field2": {
                "enum": [
                  "true"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "required": [
              "C"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Playground: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/mAPFXugk

Now the subschemas have required the keywords too, the validation works as you expect.

If you run into problems using conditionals in JSON Schema, you can test your assumptions by changing a subschema to `false`, such as the value of `then`. You can use this technique to check which conditions are met or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Having said that, I'm still curious as to why `{"field1": "REAL"}` passes the validation.